# Error while trying to merge results from different JTL files using the MergeResults PLUGIN in JMETER NON GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I've used

> java -jar /Users/Sri/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/ext/CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv results-demo3.csv --input-jtl merge-results.properties --plugin-type MergeResults** command at/bin path.merge-results.properties file is in bin folder and in place of 'inputJtl1' I've given the fileName1.jtl 'inputJtl2' has fileName2.jtl. A csv file is generated but it has no values in it It has only the names {timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime
>   }. I'm using jmeter 3.0 version and it has all plugins included.

Can someone suggest the fixes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removed the `prefixLabel` and `includeLabel` and got the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `includeLabel` from the `merge-result.properties`