# Merge Results plugin jmeter on Non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can someone share a sample line which will explain how to merge multiple jtl file into single jtl file using jmeter plugins

[Error while trying to merge results from different JTL files using the MergeResults PLUGIN in JMETER NON GUI mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016373/error-while-trying-to-merge-results-from-different-jtl-files-using-the-mergeresu/54438835?noredirect=1#comment95687127_54438835)

Answer (score 2):

1. Using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) install:

   - [Merge Results Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)
   - [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)
2. Make sure that files you're going to merge are present in JMeter's "bin" folder and called

   - `test1.csv`
   - `test2.csv`
3. Amend `merge-results.properties` file (in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) to look like:

   ```
   # === FILE 1 ===
   inputJtl1=test1.csv
   prefixLabel1=TEST1:
   includeLabels1=.*
   excludeLabelsl=
   includeLabelRegex1=true
   excludeLabelRegex1=
   startOffset1=
   endOffset1=

   # === FILE 2 ===
   inputJtl2=test2.csv
   prefixLabel2=TEST2:
   includeLabels2=.*
   excludeLabels2=
   includeLabelRegex2=true
   excludeLabelRegex2=
   startOffset2=
   endOffset2=
   ```
4. Execute the following command from "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

   ```
   PluginsManagerCMD --tool Reporter --generate-csv merged.csv --input-jtl merge-results.properties --plugin-type MergeResults
   ```
5. Open `merged.csv` file with the [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice - you should see cumulative results for both files.

Comment: Is the plugin compatible with Jmeter 5.1 version?